# Tkinter: usar un placeholder en entry

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo una simple ruleta donde pueda añadir más y más objetos, en el entry se pondrán las palabras que vayas agregando a la ruleta pero necesito un placeholder, he visto una funcion llamada .insert(0, "placeholder"), pero si lo uso me pone el texto que tengo que borrar, yo quería algo mas como una palabra que no moleste adentro del entry y con escribir una letra desaparezca como en esta pagina: https://fluky.io/ que es una ruleta, dice "Add something" y es un placeholder, no molesta y no se ve mucho...

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza `insert`

**ACTUALIZADO**

```
root = Tk()

entrada = Entry(root, width=60)
entrada.pack()
entrada.insert(0, "Tu Nombre")
entrada.configure(state = DISABLED)

def placeholder(event):
    entrada.configure(state = NORMAL)
    entrada.delete(0, END)

    entrada.unbind('<Button-1>', click)

click = entrada.bind('<Button-1>', placeholder)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: pero si puse que use insert, eso me pone un texto asi nomas y yo quiero un "placeholder" como cuando hay una caja de texto en stackoverflow y dice "escribir comentario" o algo asi, es como un texto fantasma